# Need help cancelling a web alert

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I have a web alert for the radio buttons, saying are you sure you want such and such.
When i click ok its fine, however when i click cancel it still takes me to the success.html, instead of cancelling it.

This is the validation for the radio buttons.

```
function validateForm() {



var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Exam_Type');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
         if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = inputs[i];
   }
}
if(checked==null)
{
    alert('Please choose an exam level.');
    return false;
}
else{
      confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
}
```

And these are the radio buttons if this is needed.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio"
        id="Exam_Type" 
        name="Exam_Type" 
        value="GCSE" />: GCSE
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio"
        id="Exam_Type" 
        name="Exam_Type" 
        value="A2" />: A2
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio"
        id="Exam_Type" 
        name="Exam_Type"
        value="AS" />: AS
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the code redirection to `success.html` ? show more code ...

Comment: you can try with ´===´

Comment: @JTeisseire Here is the code referring to success.html                       <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">

Comment: Side note: IDs must be unique as you are using `id="Exam_Type"`

Comment: Yes haha , i do realise that now you have pointed it out, however it isn't causing a problem do i guess i can leave it like that.

Answer (score -1):

something like this should work

```
else{
     var check = confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
     if (check == true) do something;
     else do nothing;
}
```

Comment: I do now know what you mean sir.

Comment: may be better with: else return false;

Comment: i cannot do that because i am using the else statement to bring up the alert message to ask the user if what they have chosen is correct

Comment: what I meant is the action AFTER this alert message. var check is already this message. if (check == true) is users confirmation by clicked OK button.

Comment: Oh, i get what you mean now, sorry for my stupidity, was being abit slow there.

Comment: However i tried it and everything ruined, good job i saved it as a differnt file. But yeah this makes all the validation now work :/.

Comment: Good luck, to complete the code, just replace "do something" with "self.location.href = success.html?exam_type="+checked.value, if this ist the only field needed there. Otherwise... you will know.

Comment: Thank you haha, i will try that, and above i ment to say -But yeah this makes all the validation not work :/ , I found it quite strange, but there must be a way to do this.